# div positioning for person profile

Tags: html, css

I want to create a bio page which will have a picture on the left, name, title, email, and phone to the right of the picture, and after the picture and the text to the right, some info on the person.  Here is the code I am using but it is not working.  My image and the text to the right display where I want them to, however my info div is displayed next to my name , title, etc section.

```
<div>
<div style="float:left"><img src="Images/fowler.jpg" alt="Fowler" /></div>

<div style="float:left">

<div>Name</div>
<div>Title</div>
<div>Email</div>
<div>Phone</div>

</div>

</div>

<div>Info about person</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: How about you specify some heights and widths?

Comment: <div style="clear:both">Info about person</div>

Comment: Thanks Crazyshezy that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has already said, you might want to consider using a css.
I am personally very fond of creating tables for this: this should be a good start:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="5">
    <img src="Images/fowler.jpg" alt="Fowler" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Info about person</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want, the following might work

```
<div>
<div style="float:left"><img src="Images/fowler.jpg" alt="Fowler" /></div>

<div style="float:left">

<div>Name</div>
<div>Title</div>
<div>Email</div>
<div>Phone</div>

</div>

</div>

<div style="float:left">Info about person</div>
```

BTW, think about declaring your CSS in an ext file ;)